# Where should I install a wireless l switch receiver in a room with 7 recessed lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

I have two 3-way light switches that control seven recessed lights in a room. I would like to add a wireless switch for them.

Where do I need to put the receiver?
I can access the wiring, but do I need to install the receiver between the last switch on the circuit and the first light attached to that switch? Would it be possible to replace one of the light switches with the receiver and put a blank faceplate (no switch) over it?

We are about to rent our basement as an Airbnb. The first switch in the series is on “our” part of the stairs and, ideally, I’d like to remove it and place the receiver there with a blank plate over it. The end switch of the series is in the Airbnb bedroom with the lights. Ideally, I’d like that switch to remain working and add the wireless switch to the other end of the room.

The switch I have is a Suraielec URK11A and URK21A.

I tried to upload a photo of the left side, but it was too big. Cropping didn’t change the size. It shows that  copper was on the top left. Black on the only other pole on the left (gold screw), at the bottom.

The switch being replaced is the one on the left. On that switch, there is black at the bottom right where the black screw is, and red at the top right (gold screw).

There are also white lines pig tailed together in the box.

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific wireless switch you want to install?  If so please identify it in the question.  You can edit the question.   Do you want that to be able to turn the lights on and off regardless of the positions of the existing switches?  How do you want it all to work together?  Have you considered a smart switch that can be controlled from your phone and would simply replace one of the existing ones?

Comment: very confusing description, You have 2 switches, of which one you want to hide from manual access, but have it active via wireless switch. Then you talk about the middle switch and end switch. So you have 3 switches now.

Comment: By middle, I just meant between the breaker and the end.

Comment: But maybe the best solution is to just remove the 1st switch completely, cover its hole with a blank, and install a receiver with two transmitters. If I did that, does it matter which one of the lights on the circuit I access to place the receiver?

Comment: You shouldn't have three way switches controlling lights on opposite sides of a locked door separating rented space.  Maybe what you want is a master switch for the whole rented space?  Or wireless control and monitoring of the lights in that space?  But why do you need a physical switch in your space controlling the bedroom lights in the rented space?

Comment: This is why my question exists—how to install the wireless switches in the rented space. The physical switch outside of the rented space already exists. We are converting it over. I managed to wire the receivers where two of the original switches were, rendering the original switches inactive while adding wireless switches where I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a **lot** of different 3-way switch configurations. For a typical smart switch (but not all), you need *hot* and *neutral* in the same location. There is no way to tell what you've got without opening switch boxes and checking the wiring.

*Most* of the time, that will limit you to one or the other of the two switch boxes. Sometimes neither one is suitable "as is" but if not then there is usually a possible solution using smart switches where the second switch is wireless rather than wired (e.g., Lutron Caseta + Pico remote).

More specifics will depend on your situation. Carefully open up the boxes and take pictures showing all the existing wiring (do *not* disconnect any wires) and we may be able to figure it out.

Comment: Edited. Thank you for your help. Please let me know if more pictures are needed.